# Powershell command for selecting audio device to output TTS to?

Tags: powershell, audio, text-to-speech

I have the following code for setting up TTS and sending a message through powershell:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech
$speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speak.Rate = 1
$speak.SelectVoice("Microsoft Hazel Desktop")
$speak.Volume = 50
$speak.Speak("Hello World")
```

How would I specify which audio device I would want this to be output to? It currently sends it to whatever is set as the default playback device, but I want it to play to another device.

I've looked around but can only find results concerning commands for changing the playback audio device, not sending audio to a specific device.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetInstalledVoices()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.getinstalledvoices?view=netframework-4.8#System_Speech_Synthesis_SpeechSynthesizer_GetInstalledVoices) Method to see whats available for you.

```
$speak.GetInstalledVoices() | Select -ExpandProperty VoiceInfo | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Comment: That does not answer my question mate

Answer (score 0):

Wave output is a bit tough in vanilla .net, but you can do it using the excellent [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio) library:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.speech

# assuming NAudio.dll is downloaded and put in current folder - otherwise specify absolute path
Add-Type -Path 'NAudio.dll';

function SpeakToDevice($text, $deviceNumber = -1) {
    $speak = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
    $speak.Rate = 1
    $speak.SelectVoice("Microsoft Hazel Desktop")
    $speak.Volume = 50;

    # write to memory stream
    $memstream = [System.IO.MemoryStream]::new();
    $speak.SetOutputToWaveStream($memstream);
    $speak.Speak($text);
    
    # convert to naudio stream
    $memstream.Position = 0;
    $wavStream = [NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader]::new($memstream);

    # create playback event on specified device
    $wo = [NAudio.Wave.WaveOutEvent]::new();
    $wo.DeviceNumber = $deviceNumber;
    $wo.Init($wavStream);
    
    $wo.play();

    # wait for audio to stop
    while ($wo.PlaybackState -eq 'Playing') {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50;
    }
    
    # cleanup
    $wo.Dispose(); $wavStream.Dispose(); $memstream.Dispose();
    $speak.SetOutputToNull();
}

# enumerate through all available devices and try speaking through it
get-range -stop ([NAudio.Wave.WaveOut]::DeviceCount - 1) | % {
    $deviceNumber = $_;
    $info = [NAudio.Wave.WaveOut]::GetCapabilities($deviceNumber);
    $name = $info.ProductName;
    Write-Host "Speaking on Device $deviceNumber ($name)"
    SpeakToDevice "Device Number $deviceNumber" $deviceNumber;
}
```